# Cut a long decimal fragment to exact tow decimal

Tags: android, math, int, rounding, bigdecimal

I made an application in android withthe help of decimal format #.##. but i need to get exact first tow decimals of the fractional number.i dont want to get round the number. is there any coding for that plese tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);`

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)